# replace a pipe delimiter with a space using awk or sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a pipe delimited file with a sample lines like below;

```
/u/chaintrk/bri/sh/picklist_autoprint.sh|-rwxrwxr-x|bdr|bdr|2665|Oct|23|14:04|3919089454
/u/chaintrk/bri/sh/generate_ct2020.pl|-rwxrwxr-x|bdr|bdr|15916|Oct|23|14:04|957147508
```

is there a way that awk or sed can transform the lines into the output like below where the pipe between the month and the date was replaced by space?

```
/u/chaintrk/bri/sh/picklist_autoprint.sh|-rwxrwxr-x|bdr|bdr|2665|Oct 23|14:04|3919089454
/u/chaintrk/bri/sh/generate_ct2020.pl|-rwxrwxr-x|bdr|bdr|15916|Oct 23|14:04|957147508
```

Comment: Your input and output appear to be identical to me.  Do you care to update your question?

Comment: on the input there is a pipe between the month and date (Oct|23) while on the output it needs to be replaced by a space (Oct 23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/(\|[A-Z][a-z]{2})\|([0-9]{1,2}\|)/\1 \2/' file
```

Output:

```
/u/chaintrk/bri/sh/picklist_autoprint.sh|-rwxrwxr-x|bdr|bdr|2665|Oct 23|14:04|3919089454
/u/chaintrk/bri/sh/generate_ct2020.pl|-rwxrwxr-x|bdr|bdr|15916|Oct 23|14:04|957147508
```

If you want to edit file "in place" add sed's option `-i`.

Comment: i got an invalid option when i tried it

sed -E 's/(\|[A-Z][a-z]{2})\|([0-9]{1,2}\|)/\1 \2/' testlist.txt
sed: invalid option -- E

Comment: Try this with a non GNU sed: `sed 's/\(|[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\)|\([0-9]\+|\)/\1 \2/' file`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you kindly explain how the command was able to distinguish which pipe will it replace from the line.

Comment: I have used a regex to describe what is to be searched for and replaced. Search for a pipe, followed by one capital letter, followed by two small letters, followed by a pipe, followed by at least one number and followed by a pipe. See also: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: @Cyrus please add the regex explanation to your answer it will be useful for future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to change a "|" with an space.
The real problem is to identify which of the field(s) to change.

Are those always the 6th and 7th?    If so, this works:

```
awk -vFS='|' '{sub($6"|"$7,$6" "$7)}1' file
```

Are those with a text `Upper-lower-lower` followed by a `1 or 2 digits`?
If so, this other works:

```
gawk '{c="[|]([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{2})[|]([0-9]{1,2})[|]";print gensub(c,"|\\1 \\2|",1,$0)}' file
```